# Should I test every Generic type in a generic Repository?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, repository-pattern

I am currently making tests for a Generic Repository which I implemented in an onion architecture. My Data Access is made using Entity Framework Code First.

Since I have a generic Repository, I can use just about any Entity (POCO) as a Generic type for the Repository. To illustrate this, the repo would look like this (basic repo without interface or implementation):

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
   //Code here
}
```

And now, I want to test it, so here comes my question: Do i have to use every Entities in my test? Say I have tables : Document, Category, Profile, Group and much more ...

Do I have to test all of these POCOs in this manner:

```
Repository<Document> repoDoc = new Repository<Document>();
Repository<Category> repoCat = new Repository<Category>();
//And so on for each and every table, and then apply tests to each
```

Note that I have several hundreds of tables so the idea of doing this kind of makes me sad :D

Thanks for your help!

Comment: None. Create a dummy poco and mock the repositories explicit dependencies then test that the generic class which is the subject under test behaved as expected. This however is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Nkosi Ok, I'm having a hard time to picture this, mock the repositories or their dependencies? Would you have just a small example to demonstrate this?

Comment: Mock the explicit dependencies of the repositories. What is injected into the repository class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of generics is to abstract the core code of operations that are independent of the exact type of data (or extending somehing concrete). Testing for *every* possible implementation is quite the same as not having any generics at all and testing all your implementation

So, what to test here? The same as usual: **critical code**. Take some representative examples of what your code will be dealing with and write some tests for those cases

In order to explain this a bit more: suppose you have something like this:

```
function add(int number1, number 2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

What would you test? Would you test for **every** possible pair of integers? That would make no sense! Again, choose some representative cases and test them

When testing not only you should choose representative cases but also *edge* cases. This is cases when you know some condition will be tested. For example:

```
function something(int number) {
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In that case what would you test? Well, some representative values would be -5, 10... But one importante value is **0** because it's involved in a for each and things can be a bit weird in that case

Talking about databases what could be representative cases:

- Single table
- Table with relationships (foreign keys)
- ...

And what about edge cases?

- Deletes
- Deletes with foreign keys
- Updates with foreign keys referencing objects that doesn't exist
- ...

Just some examples that come to my mind

Comment: I see, thank you. So I guess it would make sense to test an independant table, a table that establishes a relation between two tables and a table with a foreign key?

Comment: That would make sense. I'll update my answer to include some more info

Comment: @LéonardLaiter you are now delving into the realm of integration testing. tread carefully.

Comment: @Nkosi Scary times for me hah! I'll get there some day!

Comment: @Pelocho Thank you for examples, I have marked as answer :)